# how to find and click elements have a specific class and doesn't have a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in fact,  I wanna find elements that have a specific class and doesn't have a specific class, for example, I mean this is code.

in this code, we have `toggle-like` and `has-like` but I wanna find all of the elements that have `toggle-like` but doesn't have `has-like`

> please if you can write javascript and jquery code.

```
 <button class="widget-button toggle-like has-like fade-out no-text" aria-label="شما این نوشته را پسندیده‌اید" title="شما این نوشته را پسندیده‌اید" disabled="true">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

=================================

```
var sad = document.querySelectorAll("button:not([.has-like])");
    for (var i = 0; i < happy.length; i++) {
        sad[i].click();
    }
```

Comment: You need to check `:not()` selector JQuery. Here is the link: https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, for class you need to prefix `.` with class name

```
var sad = document.querySelectorAll("button.toggle-like:not(.has-like)");
//jQuery code
var sad = $("button.toggle-like:not(.has-like)");
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("button.toggle-like:not(.has-like)"))
```

```html
<button class="widget-button toggle-like has-like fade-out no-text" aria-label="شما این نوشته را پسندیده‌اید" title="شما این نوشته را پسندیده‌اید" disabled="true">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

js:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.toggle-like:not(.has-like)')
```

jq:

```
$('button.toggle-like:not(.has-like)')
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot before the class name is missing. When you put the dot '.', that way the Jquery knows you are referring to a class name.